# How to use custom scenario civilizations as a playable Civilization?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

Is there a way to "extract" a Civilization from Civilization 5 Brave New World custom scenario (not from a mod) and use it as a playable Civilization? It is okay if it involves the creation of a mod from it, the goal is just to have the extracted Civilization as a playable Civilization.

(If there's missing information i could provide please tell me in the comments, but as far as I'm concerned, the question has everything it needs to be answered)

NB: if there's a duplicate with answers on it please notify me and I'll delete this question if i find the question has answers i need.